# Getting username based profile in laravel & sentry 2 instead of user id

Tags: php, laravel, user-interface, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I am using laravel.
for authentication sentry 2.
When the user is visiting at my site they are going to the page

```
http://dolovers.com/profile/13
```

Here 13 is the user id.

I am researching to have a better procedure to find user by its username

and also I want to reduce the link by:

```
http://dolovers.com/<username>
```

how should I start with sentry2 and laravel. Thanks for the help :)
route for profile :

```
# Profile
// Route::get('profile', array('as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'Controllers\Account\ProfileController@getIndex'));
Route::get('profile', array('as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'ProfilesController@index'));
Route::post('profile', 'Controllers\Account\ProfileController@postIndex');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you find your user by id:

```
$user = Sentry::findUserById(13);
```

Or login

```
$user = Sentry::findUserByLogin('john.doe@example.com');

$user = Sentry::findUserByLogin('sagiruddin-mondal');
```

To reduce your link, you need to edit your route:

```
Route::get('/{userId}', 
             array(
                    'as' => 'user.find.get', 
                    'uses' => 'ProfilesController@index'
                  ) 
           );

Route::post('/{userId}', 
             array(
                    'as' => 'user.find.post', 
                    'uses' => 'ProfilesController@postIndex'
                  ) 
           );

Route::get('/', 
             array(
                    'as' => 'home', 
                    'uses' => 'HomeController@index'
                  ) 
           );
```

It should let you use route like

```
http://dolovers.com/<userid>
```

And also let you create urls using

```
URL::route('user.find.get', array(13));

URL::route('user.find.post', array(13));
```

I also define a second route (home) to point to

```
http://dolovers.com/
```

Your UsersController would look like:

```
class UsersController extends Controller {

    protected function findUser($username)
    {
        if ( ! $user = Sentry::findUserByLogin('sagiruddin-mondal'))
        {
            return "user not found";
        }

         return $user->name;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! I have lill changed in the question .. I wanted to write user name instead of user id . Sorry , pls chk it :)

Comment: how http://dolovers.com/username  (which is not a mail id) can be pointed to a router ? and what the controller should be react at ? is it receiving username in the id variable ?

Comment: It's the login, whatever you are using, e-mail or username. Edited to clarify. Created a controller to show you a little bit more.

Comment: Sir I ve added the current route structure there ! Can you pls tell me sould I keep it ?

Comment: You should not keep them, you don't need to keep them, unless you have other uses for them, of course. Edited to add your post route.

Comment: its giving error 'missing parameter'

`Route::post('/{userId}', `

should not be like this ?

Route::post('/{username}',

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42216/discussion-between-antonio-carlos-ribeiro-and-sagiruddin-mondal)